# JavaScript Document.Write() Displays in Blank Page (Removed HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>Here is a message: <span id="message"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

​

```
function nextMsg() {
    if (messages.length == 0) {
        document.write("Done");
    } else {
        $('#message').html(messages.pop()).fadeIn(500).delay(100).fadeOut(500, nextMsg);
    }
};

var messages = [
    "Hello!",
    "This is a website!",
].reverse();

$('#message').hide();
nextMsg();
​
```

The javascript simply runs through the given text strings and when done runs `document.write("Done");`

Notice that after the Hello!, and This is a Website! Are displayed, the `document.write("Done");` function is displayed in a separate page removing all the HTML.

How can I display permanent text after the Hello and Website text appear..? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: don't use `document.write()`. since you're already using jQuery, why not just do ` $('#message').html('Done!')`?

Comment: You would never need to do that anyway. But your fiddle is set to Mootools.onload instead use .html("...") of some container

Comment: See [*2. `document.write` executes after the page has finished loading and will overwrite the page, or **write a new page,**...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Comment: You've got jQuery in that code. Why are you asking us how to put stuff on the DOM. You're already doing it, and `document.write` is a dead method.

Comment: `document.write`... haven't use (or even see) this since long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this:

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>Here is a message:</p>
<p id="message"></p>​
```

This is in a `window.onload` block that jsFiddle takes care of:

```
var messages = ["Hello!","This is a website!"];

(function nextMsg() {
    $('#message')
        .fadeIn(1500)
        .delay(500)
        .fadeOut(1500, !messages.length || nextMsg)
        .html(messages.shift() || 'Done');
})();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/5s8y3/100/